# HttpClient SSLException

Tags: java, ssl, https, httpclient

I try to send https request to a web service and after few successful attempts, I start getting this error consistently. What does this error mean, and why does it happen on the first time itself.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1842)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1825)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1751)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.flush(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:102)
    at org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity.writeTo(StringEntity.java:94)
    at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:96)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:263)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.sendRequestEntity(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:227)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:255)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:622)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:454)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:941)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:919)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:910)
    at com.nim.service.push.exacttarget.ExactTargetPushService.sendMessageContacts(ExactTargetPushService.java:208)
    at com.nim.service.push.exacttarget.ExactTargetPushService.sendPushNotification(ExactTargetPushService.java:106)
    at com.nim.domain.push.PushManager.pushHelper(PushManager.java:91)
    at com.nim.domain.push.PushManager.pushEntitlementChange(PushManager.java:40)
    at com.nim.domain.push.PushManager.pushEntitlementChange(PushManager.java:36)
    at com.nim.domain.push.PushManager.pushEntitlementChange(PushManager.java:51)
    at com.nim.batch.entitlement.SubscriptionEntitlementWriter.pushClientNotifications(SubscriptionEntitlementWriter.java:161)
    at com.nim.batch.entitlement.SubscriptionEntitlementReader.retrievePage(SubscriptionEntitlementReader.java:71)
    at com.nim.batch.entitlement.SubscriptionEntitlementReader.retrievePage(SubscriptionEntitlementReader.java:1)
    at com.nim.batch.entitlement.EntitlementPagedDifferentialReader.read(EntitlementPagedDifferentialReader.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor96.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:90)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:87)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:108)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:103)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:68)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:386)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:264)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:76)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:250)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.<init>(ECDHCrypt.java:80)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverKeyExchange(ClientHandshaker.java:692)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:274)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:878)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:814)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:702)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: parameter object not a ECParameterSpec
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyPairGenerator$EC.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.<init>(ECDHCrypt.java:75)
    ... 72 more
```

Comment: It looks like something may be missing in the supporting classes for ECDH (elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman) key-pair generation. Can't tell much more than that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had this same problem. This article helped me: http://iwang.github.io/support/2014/03/14/cxf-cause-https-error.html

In essence, the problem is that you are using Bouncy Castle JDK1.4 libraries instead of the more recent 1.5 libraries.

To fix the problem, I removed Bouncy Castle completely. I found it was being pulled in by an unrelated library, so I added the following to the dependency in the pom.xml file:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bctsp-jdk14</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
<exclusions>
```

If you can't remove it, I suggest updating to the jdk15 libraries.

The explanation from the linked article:

> Java 1.5 introduced a change to the elliptical curve cryptography API.
>   If you use a Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) >provider intended for
>   Java 1.4 or earlier it will not support this new API change and there
>   may be errors with Diffie-Hellman based ciphers when using SSL. The
>   SSL implementation attempts to setup elliptical curve cryptography
>   with a ECGenParameterSpec object. This object wasn't added to until Java 1.5:
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/spec/ECGenParameterSpec.html
>   (Notice the Since line).
>
> For example, the bcprov-jdk14-131-1.0.jar is Bouncy Castle which is
>   one such provider. This version of the provider is intended for JDK
>   1.4. Bouncy Castle provides different libraries for each JDK level.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am in process of confirming this fix. Do you know which bouncycastle library exactly is the culprit? is it bcprov-jdk14, bctsp-jdk14 or bcmail-jdk14?

Comment: As far as I am aware, all of them. They were just the libraries pulled in by my dependency. I used the Dependency Hierarchy view in Eclipse to work out the offending library (in my case, iText).

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue some time..I got it to work fine after upgrading from 
`bcprov-jdk14` to `bcprov-jdk15`

Comment: Thank you ! it worked for me as well .. i downloaded it from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/b/Downloadbcprovjdk15146jar.htm

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and was unable to use BC15 since we still have legacy support for some 1.4 clients (old unix OS clients).  Given this limitation, I was able to work around the problem by including the ECGenParameterSpec.java class in package java.security.spec.  Don't copy the Java one from the 1.5 sources; it has Oracle copyright all over it.  Here's an example implementation that is Apache Licensed.  As you can see, the class is not terribly complex and I'm sure you can write your own.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/a47f800/luni/src/main/java/java/security/spec/ECGenParameterSpec.java

```
/*
 *  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 *  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 *  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 *  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 *  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 *  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 */
package java.security.spec;
/**
 * The parameter specification used to generate elliptic curve domain parameters.
 */
public class ECGenParameterSpec implements AlgorithmParameterSpec {
    // Standard (or predefined) name for EC domain
    // parameters to be generated
    private final String name;
    /**
     * Creates a new {@code ECGenParameterSpec} with the specified standard or
     * predefined name of the to-be-generated domain parameter.
     *
     * @param name
     *            the name of the elliptic curve domain parameter.
     */
    public ECGenParameterSpec(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        if (this.name == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Returns the name (standard or predefined) of the to-be-generated elliptic
     * curve domain parameter.
     *
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Including this file in your project sources (exclude from proguard, etc if you need to), and you're set (at least for this error).

Answer (score 0):

Even I ran into the same issue, but in my application I was not allowed to upgrade the bounty castle jars.

Problem :
We had a common API for google translation using google api, and that API used to do a https request to google API, because bounty castle was also registered as one of the JCE provider and was used for encryption and we used to get exact error.

I solved this issue by following few steps without upgrading bounty castle jars.
Before doing the https call, what I did was removed bounty castle fro security provider list and did the https call so that Sun's JCE provider is used for encryption. This worked out well for me.
Remove Bounty castle from service provider list at runtime by below code, and before removing it I took the bounty castle provider instance and added it again after https call is done.

Code below

```
java.security.Provider provider = java.security.Security.getProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME); 
java.security.Security.removeProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
int index = getProviderIndex(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
String url = "some https url";
org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod method = new org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod(url);
int responseCode = HTTP_CLIENT.executeMethod(method);
if(provider != null && index >= 0)
     java.security.Security.insertProviderAt(provider, (index+1));


private int getProviderIndex(String name) {
    final Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();
    /**
     * Just to log available providers
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < providers.length; i++) {
        Provider provider = providers[i];
        LOGGER.error(provider.getName() + " " + provider.getVersion() + ": " + provider.getInfo());
    }

    for(int index = 0; index < providers.length; index++){
        if (providers[index] != null && providers[index].getName() != null
                && providers[index].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.54</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Please elaborate a little bit more on this to make it easier for all of us to understand the crucial point.

Comment: To further elaborate for anyone that bumps into this thread. You add this dependency to the pom.xml file