# SSL Exceptions Seemingly caused by Apache Axis2

Tags: java, ssl, apache-axis, apache-commons-httpclient

So my question is this: does axis2 create / override a global SSL factory that would impact other parts of a project that are communicating without using axis2?

I have a method making http calls out to an external page using org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient (Below).  It works.  I send things out, and get responses back, everything is awesome.

```
PostMethod method = new PostMethod(url);
    method.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    method.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken);
    method.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(requestAsString, "application/json", "UTF-8"));

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setSoTimeout(timeout);


    int rCode = client.executeMethod(method);
```

I also have database connections using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.  It works. Everything is still awesome.

The problems start with another service within the same project that uses axis2 (org.apache.axis2-1.6.2).  After I attempt any communication using the axis 2 stub both the jdbc connection and the HttpClient connection both begin failing (The errors are below).  Everything works fine up until axis2 gets involved.

I know axis2 is based on commons-httpclient-3.1 so the impact to the HttpClient piece isn't entirely unexpected but I cannot for the life of me figure out why I am seeing this behavior.

My assumption is that axis2 is setting some sort of global variable that is impacting ssl connections but having read the documentation and stepped through the source code, I can't find that happening anywhere.

The HttpClient error:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1917)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1874)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1857)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1783)
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:128)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.StringRequestEntity.writeRequest(StringRequestEntity.java:146)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
... 10 more

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
at sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.<init>(ECDHCrypt.java:79)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverKeyExchange(ClientHandshaker.java:696)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:277)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:936)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:871)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1043)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:728)
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
... 16 more

Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: parameter object not a ECParameterSpec
at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyPairGenerator$EC.initialize(JDKKeyPairGenerator.java:345)
at sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.<init>(ECDHCrypt.java:74)
... 24 more
```

The jdbc error:

```
    ERROR  13:27:33,321 [Thread-24] PID- M- TID- DAConnectionMgr_MSSQL -DB connection unavaliable to [master] as [Dev_User] failed on attempt [2], will automatically retry
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server returned an incomplete response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:a67d09bf-be47-4910-9d8c-fd040468a1cb".
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1667)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1668)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1323)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at com.company.util.da.DAConnectionMgr_MSSQL.getConnection(DAConnectionMgr_MSSQL.java:299)
at com.company.baseserver.da.payments.product.productSSQL.openConnection(Product10DAMSSQL.java:499)
at com.company.baseserver.payments.product.ProductProcessor.process(ProductPaymentProcessor.java:988)
at com.company.baseserver.message.ProjectFunction.process(ProjectFunction.java:108)
at com.company.base.ClientProcessor.run(ClientProcessor.java:93)
at com.company.util.thread.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(PooledExecutor.java:774)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: SQL Server returned an incomplete response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:a67d09bf-be47-4910-9d8c-fd040468a1cb
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.ensureSSLPayload(IOBuffer.java:651)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:708)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:700)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:895)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:883)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:954)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1618)
... 13 more
```

Comment: have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26771728/3166303

Comment: @leeor : No I had not, thanks.  I've only ran one test so I could be jumping the gun, but I think an outdated bcprov-jdk14 jar might have been the culprit for at least one of these errors if not both.  Thanks again.

Comment: I replaced bcprov-jdk14 with bcprov-jdk15on and have tested enough that I am confident that was the issue.  Everything seems to be working now.